# Python Formatting Output

Tags: python, formatting, output

I have the following code:

```
import options
import random


class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.gold = 100
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.levelUp = 50
        self.gainedexp = self.levelUp - self.exp


    def get_name(self):
        self.name = input("Hey there, traveller! What's your name?\n~~>")
        print("Since you are new around here, 100 gold doubloons have been given to you, {}!".format(self.name))

    def gold_counter(self):
        print("You currently have {} gold!".format(player.gold))


class Dragon():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dragon"
        self.dropgold = random.randint(13,20)
        self.minexp = int(15 * round(player.level * 1.5))
        self.maxexp = int(30 * round(player.level * 1.5))  
        self.expgain = random.randint({}, {}.format(self.minexp, self.maxexp))
        self.maxhealth = 80
        self.health = self.maxhealth




def intro():
    wrong_input = 0
    nar_name = "Narrator"
    print("{}: Uhhhm...".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: Let me check my list...".format(nar_name))
    print("{0}: Ah! Yes! {1}, that's right. I heard you were supposed to be arriving today.".format(nar_name, player.name))
```

I am also using two other modules, but I'm 99% sure they don't affect this. I get the following output:

```
Hey there, traveller! What's your name?
~~>Savage Potato
Since you are new around here, 100 gold doubloons have been given to you, Savage Potato!
Do you want to see your balance?
~~> Yes
You currently have 100 gold.
Narrator: Uhhhm...
Narrator: Let me check my list...
Narrator: Ah! Yes! None, that's right. I heard you were supposed to be arriving today.
```

In the last line, it is printing out the Narrator's name, but not the user's inputted name. I also looked at the python documents on [their website](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), but I couldn't find a fix. Any ideas on how I could stop it from outputting `None` as the user's name?

EDIT #1: I have player = Player() written later in the module.

EDIT #2: This is all the code I used:

## Module 1 (main.py)

```
import prints
import random

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.gold = 100
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.levelUp = 50
        self.gainedexp = self.levelUp - self.exp


    def get_name(self):
        self.name = input("Hey there, traveller! What's your name?\n~~>")
        print("Since you are new around here, 100 gold doubloons have been given to you, {}!".format(self.name))




class Dragon():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dragon"
        self.dropgold = random.randint(13,20)
        self.minexp = int(15 * round(player.level * 1.5))
        self.maxexp = int(30 * round(player.level * 1.5))  
        self.expgain = random.randint({}, {}.format(self.minexp, self.maxexp))
        self.maxhealth = 80
        self.health = self.maxhealth




#while player.exp >= player.levelUp:
    #player.levelUp += 1
    #player.exp = player.exp - player.levelUp
    #player.levelUp = round(player.levelUp * 1.5)
    #print("Congrats! You just levelled up to level {} by gaining {} experience!".format(player.level, player.gainedexp))


def start():
    player.get_name()
    prints.gold_counter()
    prints.intro()
    prints.encounter()





player = Player()    


start()
```

## Module 2 (prints.py)

```
import options
import random


class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.gold = 100
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.levelUp = 50
        self.gainedexp = self.levelUp - self.exp


    def get_name(self):
        self.name = input("Hey there, traveller! What's your name?\n~~>")
        print("Since you are new around here, 100 gold doubloons have been given to you, {}!".format(self.name))

    def gold_counter(self):
        print("You currently have {} gold!".format(player.gold))


class Dragon():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dragon"
        self.dropgold = random.randint(13,20)
        self.minexp = int(15 * round(player.level * 1.5))
        self.maxexp = int(30 * round(player.level * 1.5))  
        self.expgain = random.randint({}, {}.format(self.minexp, self.maxexp))
        self.maxhealth = 80
        self.health = self.maxhealth




def intro():
    wrong_input = 0
    nar_name = "Narrator"
    print("{}: Uhhhm...".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: Let me check my list...".format(nar_name))
    print("{0}: Ah! Yes! {1}, that's right. I heard you were supposed to be arriving today.".format(nar_name, player.name))
    print("{}: Welcome to... THE DRAGON FIGHTER GAME!".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: I know, it isn't the most imaginative name.".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: Don't look at me like that, I tried my hardest!".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: Anyhoo, let's carry on.".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: For some stupid reason, the creator of this game didn't give me an actual name, so\nmy name is just \"Narrator\" or \"N\", but you can call me Larry.".format(nar_name))
    while True:
        option = input("Narrator: Actually, which name would you prefer to call me?\n").upper()
        if option in options.nar_larry_opt:
            nar_name = "Larry"
        elif option in options.nar_narrator_opt:
            nar_name = "Narrator"
            while True:
                ask = input("{}: Maybe \"N\" for short?".format(nar_name)).upper()
                if ask in options.inp_yes_opt:
                    nar_name = "N"
                elif ask in options.inp_no_opt:
                    break
                else:
                    wrong_input += 1
                    if wrong_input == 1:  
                        print("Please try again.")
                    elif wrong_input == 2:
                        print("Try to not put the same thing in next time.")
                    elif wrong_input == 3:
                        print("This isn't funny.")
                    elif wrong_input == 4:
                        print("Seriously.")
                    elif wrong_input == 5:
                        print("OKAY! THIS IS IT! GO BACK TO THE BEGINNING!")
                        intro()

                    continue
                break
        else:
            print("Please try again.")
            continue
        break
    print("{}: So, as I was saying, this game is basically just some dragon quest thingy.".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: You'll probably get tips from me every now and again if I can be bothered.".format(nar_name))
    print("{}: I'll get an test encounter ready.".format(nar_name))



def gold_counter():
    while True:
        option = input("Do you want to see your balance?\n~~> ").upper()
        if option in options.inp_yes_opt:
            print("You currently have {} gold.".format(player.gold))
        elif option in options.inp_no_opt:
            print("You can check your balance later in the game.")
        else:
            print("Please try again.")
            continue
        break



def encounter():
    while True:
        dragon_appear = random.randint(1,2)
        if dragon_appear == 1:
            print("What's that? Looks like a huge bir... \nA DRAGON! A MAJESTIC DRAGON JUST FLEW DOWN FROM THE SKY!")
        else:
            print("What's that? Looks like a huge bir... \n Yeah. Just a giganta-bird.")

    while encounter().dragon_appear != 2:
        print("So that's the message you'll get when a dragon appears.")
        print("And you will be prompted whether you want to run or fight, like so:")
        while True:
            wrong_input = 0
            ask = input("Run away like a coward, or fight the majestic beast?")
            if ask in options.enc_run_opt:
                escape = random.randint(1,2)
                if escape == 1:
                    print("You managed to get away!")
                else:
                    print("You didn't get away. Better luck next time!")
            elif ask in options.enc_attack_opt:
                pass
            else:
                wrong_input += 1
                if wrong_input == 1:  
                    print("Please try again.")
                elif wrong_input == 2:
                    print("Try to not put the same thing in next time.")
                elif wrong_input == 3:
                    print("This isn't funny.")
                elif wrong_input == 4:
                    print("Seriously.")
                continue
            break




player = Player()
```

## Module 3 (options.py)

```
inp_yes_opt = {"Y", "YE", "YES", "YEAH", "PLEASE", "YES PLEASE"}
inp_no_opt = {"N", "NO", "NOPE", "NAH"}

nar_larry_opt = {"LARRY", "LARR", "LAR", "LA", "L", "LARRY PLEASE"}
nar_narrator_opt = {"NARRATOR", "NARR", "N", "NAR", "NARRATE", "NOT LARRY"}

enc_run_opt = {"RUN", "RU", "R", "SCRAM", "RUN AWAY", "RUUUUN"}
enc_attack_opt = {"ATTACK", "ATTAK", "A", "FIGHT", "F", "ATTACK", ""}
```

Comment: It seems you are not using the same instance of Player, try to create it into intro function, it should work

Comment: I'll try it, and I'll get back to you. I just thought it would've been simpler to just make it into a class and then call it when I need to. It just makes more sense in my head to have it in the class..

Comment: You should see the visibility of your object. If it's global it works because every function has access to it, but if it's local for example you've put it into a function or in another class it won't keep memory of the changes because you are referring to another object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print out the name of the player , you need to pass in the player object to the intro function as a parameter. That assumes intro is not capturing the player object and the player object is not global

At the moment , it seems there is no player object accessible to the scope of the function which is why it outputs None

Comment: Could you share the code that calls the intro function ?

Comment: I'm imagining if this function is defined at the very top, it's not able to capture the player instance like you are intending so you should pass in player as a parameter and it will solve your issue

Comment: Yeah, just added all the code that I'm currently using. I can't really seem to spot much wrong with it. I have also tried to call the class(es) from main.py into prints.py by doing `from main import Player()`, `from main import class Player()`, `from main import *`, `import main`, and none of these work, but what I'm doing now is fine, so I'll fix it at a later date.